# Calculating the width of the interval defined by an inequality

Tags: function-construction, inequalities

I am looking for a Mathematica function that takes an inequality as the input and gives back the width defined by upper bound - lower bound:

Example:

```
Fn[1 <= x <= 2.5]
```

> `1.5`

If the inequality is evaluated to `False` (e.g., 2 <= x <= 1), then I need the function to return 0.

I truly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 12):

```
f[ineq_, var_] := RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[ineq, var], Length[Flatten[{var}]]]

f[1 <= x <= 2.5, x]
```

> 1.5

This works also for some systems of inequalities in several variables:

```
f[{1 <= x <= 2.5, 0 <= y <= x}, {x, y}]
```

> 2.625

Edit:

This one-argument version treats all symbols in the first argument as variables:

```
f[ineq_] := f[ineq, DeleteDuplicates[Cases[ineq, _Symbol]]]
```

Comment: When the dimension of the region is less than `Length[var]`, for example a line embedded in the 2D plane, then `RegionMeasure` gives the measure in the reduced dimension: `f[{1 <= x <= 2.5, y == 0}, {x, y}]` gives `1.5` (the length of the line instead of its area), which is not what's usually expected. Fix this with `f[ineq_, var_] := 
 RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[ineq, var], Length[var]]`, so that now `f[{1 <= x <= 2.5, y == 0}, {x, y}]` gives `0` as expected (the line has zero area).

Comment: Good point! Thank your for remark; I fixed it. I should have been more cautious; these dimensional issues with regions is actually a frequent source of confusion.

Comment: I was too fast in commenting: the function now doesn't work for `var=x` since `Length[x]=0`. Maybe two separate definitions for `var_Symbol` (using dimension `1`) and for `var_List` (using dimensions `Length[var]`)?

Comment: Yes even better!

Answer (score 4):

```
fn[expr_] := Module[{},
  If[! expr, Return [0]];
  If[Head[expr] == Inequality, Return[Abs[expr[[5]] - expr[[1]]]]];
  Return[Abs[expr[[3]] - expr[[1]]]];
  ]

fn[2 <= x <= 1]
(*0*)

fn[1 <= x <= 2.5]
(*1.5*)

fn[2.5 > x > 1]
(*1.5*)
```

Don't know if this works in all cases, but works in the simple cases you provide plus some.

Answer (score 3):

To get a function that would handle the all the kinds of arguments I want it to handle turned out to be more of a challenge than I anticipated, but here is what I came up with.

#### Edit

This version is handle expressions that evaluate to `False` more robustly.

```
ClearAll[fn, helper1, helper2]

SetAttributes[fn, HoldFirst]
fn[expr_] := If[expr, helper1[expr], helper2[expr], helper1[expr]]

SetAttributes[helper1, HoldFirst]
helper1[expr : _Inequality | _Less | _LessEqual | _Greater | _GreaterEqual] :=
  Module[{args = List @@ Unevaluated[expr], a, b},
    {a, b} = MinMax[Select[args, NumericQ]];
    b - a]
helper1[___] = $Failed;

SetAttributes[helper2, HoldFirst]
helper2[expr : _Inequality | _Less | _LessEqual | _Greater | _GreaterEqual] := 0;
helper2[___] = $Failed;

###Tests

fn[1 < x <= 2.5]
```

> `1.5`

```
fn[1 < x <= π]
```

> `-1 + π`

```
fn[1 >= x > π]
```

> `0`

```
fn[1 >= x > -1]
```

> `2`

```
fn[-1 < 1 <= 2.5]
```

> `3.5`

```
fn[1 < x < 3 < y < 5]
```

> `4`

```
fn[1.5 < 2]
```

> `0.5`

```
fn["garbage"]
```

> `$Failed`

```
fn[1 == 1]
```

> `$Failed`

```
 fn[1 != 1]
```

> `$Failed`